# boundingRectWithSize gives height with truncated text

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am using the following method to determine the height required to display the text that i have. However i cannot get the correct height without truncating the text at the end.

```
CGRect labelRect = [comment boundingRectWithSize:headerMax
                                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |
                                                         NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                                 context:nil];
```

How can i say not to determine the required label height without truncating the text at the end. I want the whole text to fit into the label.

Comment: is the label created programamtically ?

Comment: yes and i have set the following properties         labelView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        labelView.numberOfLines = 2;

Comment: why dont your use word wrap ?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(CGRect)getLabelSizeWithText:(NSString *)textLabel forFontSize:(CGFloat) fontSize
{
CGRect textRect;

if (textLabel != nil)
{
    NSAttributedString *actualString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textLabel attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:fontSize]} ];
    NSStringDrawingContext *targetContext = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    CGFloat commentLabelWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width;
    textRect = [actualString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(commentLabelWidth, 900) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:targetContext];
}

return textRect;
}
```

This one should work. Try it

Comment: This code will work. Could you be more specific on the reason it does not work ??

Comment: please add NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
1. If you want word wrap -

 labelView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; 
 labelView.numberOfLines = 2;

CGRect labelRect = [comment boundingRectWithSize:headerMax
                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |
                                                     NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading | NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                             context:nil];


2. If you Don't want truncating tail at all -


  // No line break mode
  labelView.numberOfLines = 0;

CGRect labelRect = [comment boundingRectWithSize:headerMax
                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |
                                                     NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                             context:nil];
```

Comment: no it still truncates at the end. And i need the text to be on two lines at most.

Comment: you have to remove this line also from your code - labelView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

Comment: if i remove   labelView.lineBreakMode it defaults to NSLineBreakByWordWrapping. I dont need wordWrapping. I need to show the entire text

Comment: yes that doesn't work. When i do that the text goes on multiple lines

Comment: you don't want text truncation, word wrap or more line?? what do you want??

Comment: i want the entire text to be displayed.  Read my question

Comment: Do you want all text to be fit in 2 lines itself??

Comment: just add this line with what you had earlier [labelView sizeToFit];

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *cellText = restaurant.review;
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: cellFont};
CGRect labelSize = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure whether I understood your question correctly; it sounds like you are trying to calculate the `frame` size needed to display the text and setting the `frame` manually with that. Additionally, by setting `.numberOfLines = 2`, you are limiting the text that you can show. My suggestion would be for you to set up constraints via `autolayout`, optionally add a `.minimumScaleFactor` and let it dynamically resize itself.

If you still want to calculate size, with `numberOfLines` taken into consideration, you can use a prototype label and have use its height

```
- (CGSize)preferredSizeForString:(NSString *)string 
                           width:(CGFloat)width
{
    UILabel *prototypelabel = [UILabel new];
    prototypelabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,  width, 0);
    prototypelabel.text = @"Your string";
    prototypelabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    [prototypelabel sizeToFit];

    return prototypelabel.frame.size;
}
```